# If $A$ and $B$ have independent columns/rows then $AB$ has them as well.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

To prove this on column bases, I wrote out $r_1 c_{a_1} + \dots + r_n c_{a_n} = 0 \implies r_1 = \dots = r_n = 0$ and  $r_1 c_{b_1} + \dots + r_n c_{b_n} = 0 \implies r_1 = \dots = r_n =0$. But I am unsure if this is related to $AB$.

Comment: Well, if $A$ and $B$ are square
$$0\ne\det(A),~\, 0\ne\det(B)\hspace{5mm}\implies\hspace{5mm}0\ne\det (A)\det(B)=\det (AB)$$

Comment: You know $Ax=0 \implies x=0$ and $By=0\implies y=0$.  So you need to prove $ABy=0\implies y=0$.  Start your proof "Suppose $y$ is a vector such that $ABy=0$."